# Difference in sequence of query generated in Django and Postgres for select_for_update

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

I'm facing a strange situation, where sequence of query logged in Django and Postgres is different when using `select_for_update()` inside `transaction.atomic()` block.

Basically I've a `ModelForm` where I'm validating the `cleaned_data` against the database, for duplicate request. And then in create view's `form_valid()` method, I'm saving the instance. To have both the operation inside same transaction, I'm overriding `post()` method, and wrapping those two method calls inside `transaction.atomic()`.

Here's the code for whatever I said above:

```
# Form
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
        super(MenuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MenuForm, self).clean()
        dish_name = cleaned_data.get('dish_name')
        menus = Menu.objects.select_for_update().filter(user_id=self.user_id)

        for menu in menus:
            if menu.dish_name == dish_name:
                self.add_error('dish_name', 'Dish already exists')
                return cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data

# CreateView
class MenuCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = MenuForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MenuCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user_id': self.request.session.get('user_id')})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.session.get('user_id'))
        form.instance.user = user
        return super(MenuCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()

        with transaction.atomic():
            if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Now suppose I fire two request at the same time, to create a menu with same dish. I expect the second request to fail. But, both of them are passing. It looks like, the second transaction is not seeing the changes done in previous transaction. Because of which, the total `menus` remain the same in both the transaction that is returned by `select_for_update()`.

Given that Postgres default Isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`, I expect the changes to be visible. So, I tried logging the queries to see that COMMIT; is fired at right time. Here's the query log by django and in postgres:

### Django Log:

```
SELECT "menu"."id", "menu"."dish_id", "menu"."dish_name" FROM "menu" WHERE ("menu"."dish_name" = "Test Dish") FOR UPDATE; args=("Test Dish")    
INSERT INTO "menu" ("dish_id", "dish_name") VALUES (2, "Test Dish") RETURNING "menu"."id"; args=(2, "Test Dish")
SELECT "menu"."id", "menu"."dish_id", "menu"."dish_name" FROM "menu" WHERE ("menu"."dish_name" = "Test Dish") FOR UPDATE; args=("Test Dish")
INSERT INTO "menu" ("dish_id", "dish_name") VALUES (2, "Test Dish") RETURNING "menu"."id"; args=(2, "Test Dish")
```

### Postgres Log:

```
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.176 IST  0  2/31  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.177 IST  0  2/32  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.178 IST  0  2/33  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: SELECT t.oid, typarray
    FROM pg_type t JOIN pg_namespace ns
        ON typnamespace = ns.oid
    WHERE typname = 'hstore';

<2016-03-18 17:55:46.182 IST  0  2/34  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: BEGIN
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.301 IST  0  3/2  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.302 IST  0  3/3  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.302 IST  0  3/4  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: SELECT t.oid, typarray
    FROM pg_type t JOIN pg_namespace ns
        ON typnamespace = ns.oid
    WHERE typname = 'hstore';

<2016-03-18 17:55:46.312 IST  0  3/5  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: BEGIN
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.963 IST  0  3/5  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: SELECT "menu"."id", "menu"."dish_id", "menu"."dish_name" FROM "menu" 
WHERE ("menu"."dish_name" = "Test Dish") FOR UPDATE
<2016-03-18 17:55:46.964 IST  0  2/34  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: SELECT "menu"."id", "menu"."dish_id", "menu"."dish_name" FROM "menu" 
WHERE ("menu"."dish_name" = "Test Dish") FOR UPDATE
<2016-03-18 17:55:47.040 IST  23712  3/5  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "menu" ("dish_id", "dish_name") VALUES (2, "Test Dish")RETURNING "menu"."id"
<2016-03-18 17:55:47.061 IST  23712  3/5  56ebf3ca.aac1>LOG:  statement: COMMIT
<2016-03-18 17:55:47.229 IST  23713  2/34  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "menu" ("dish_id", "dish_name") VALUES (2, "Test Dish")RETURNING "menu"."id"
<2016-03-18 17:55:47.231 IST  23713  2/34  56ebf3ca.aac0>LOG:  statement: COMMIT
```

### Postgres.conf:

```
max_connections = 100
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_line_prefix = '<%m  %x  %v  %c>'
log_statement = 'all'
```

As you can see, the order of SELECT and INSERT queries in not the same in both the logs. I'm unable to understand why this would happen. Also, if you notice, the session_id for the SELECT queries in Postgres log is different. Could that explain something here?

And if this is expected behaviour, how could I solve the core issue here? Avoid concurrent INSERT queries, based on existing record.

### **UPDATE**:

I didn't mention that the actual logic to ignore duplicate menu is not just based on dish name. The one above is simplified example.

Considering menu model as:

```
class Menu:
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish)
    order_start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    order_end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

The actual logic goes like this:

- Fetch all menu with the `dish_name` from db.
- Check the `order_start_time` and `order_end_time` for all the those menu, and see if any of them overlaps with the `order_start_time` and `order_end_time` for the new menu. If conflict found, avoid addition.

So, we can add two menu for dish - `d1`, having order window - `[9am-10am]` and `[2pm-3pm]`.

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED:**

### How to make Django validate overlapping reservations?

It is possible to add special method for a model `validate_unique`:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.validators import ValidationError
    from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

    class Dish(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Dish name', max_length=200)

    class Menu(models.Model):
        user_id = models.IntegerField()
        dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish)
        order_start_time = models.DateTimeField()
        order_end_time = models.DateTimeField()

        def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # call inherited unique validators
            super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)  # or super(Menu, self) for Python2.7
            # query if DB already has object with same dish 
            # and overlapping reservation 
            # [order_start_time, order_end_time]
            qs = self.__class__._default_manager.filter(
                    order_start_time__lte=self.order_end_time,
                    order_end_time__gte=self.order_start_time,
                    dish=self.dish,
                )
            # and this object is not the same we are working with
            if not self._state.adding and self.pk is not None:
                qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            if qs.exists():
                raise ValidationError({
                    NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ['Overlapping order dates for dish'],
                    })
```

Lets try it in console:

```
    from core.models import *
    m=Menu(user_id=1, dish_id=1, order_start_time='2016-03-22 10:00', order_end_time='2016-03-22 15:00')
    m.validate_unique()
    # no output here - all is ok
    m.save()
    print(m.id)
    8

    # lets add duplicate
    m=Menu(user_id=1, dish_id=1, order_start_time='2016-03-22 12:00', order_end_time='2016-03-22 13:00')
    m.validate_unique()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/Users/el/tmp/hypothesis_test/menu/core/models.py", line 29, in validate_unique
           NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ['Overlapping order dates for dish'],
    django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'__all__': ['Overlapping order dates for dish']}

    # excellent!  dup is found!

    # But! Django helps you find dups but allows you to add them to db if you want it!
    # It's responsibility of your application not to add duplicates.

    m.save()
    print(m.id)
    9
```

### How to be sure noboby can add duplicate?

In this case you need to make a CONSTRAINT on database-level.

In PostgreSQL console:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

    -- our table:
    SELECT * FROM core_menu;
    id | user_id |    order_start_time    |     order_end_time     | dish_id
   ----+---------+------------------------+------------------------+---------
     8 |       1 | 2016-03-22 13:00:00+03 | 2016-03-22 18:00:00+03 |       1
     9 |       1 | 2016-03-22 15:00:00+03 | 2016-03-22 16:00:00+03 |       1

    DELETE FROM core_menu WHERE id=9; -- we should remove dups before adding unique constraint

    ALTER TABLE core_menu 
        ADD CONSTRAINT core_menu_exclude_dish_same_tstzrange_constr 
            EXCLUDE USING gist (dish_id WITH =, tstzrange(order_start_time, order_end_time)  WITH &&);
```

Now lets create the duplicate object and add it to db:

```
    m=Menu(user_id=1, dish_id=1, order_start_time='2016-03-22 13:00', order_end_time='2016-03-22 14:00')

    m.save()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/el/tmp/hypothesis_test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
         return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    psycopg2.IntegrityError: ОШИБКА:  конфликтующее значение ключа нарушает ограничение-исключение "core_menu_exclude_dish_same_tstzrange_constr"
    DETAIL:  Key (dish_id, tstzrange(order_start_time, order_end_time))=(1, ["2016-03-22 13:00:00+00","2016-03-22 14:00:00+00")) conflicts with existing key (dish_id, tstzrange(order_start_time, order_end_time))=(1, ["2016-03-22 10:00:00+00","2016-03-22 15:00:00+00")).
```

Excellent!
Now data is validated at program and db levels.

Comment: Actually the actual logic to compute the duplicate is tricky, and can't be achieved using unique_together. I'm trying to avoid menu addition, where the order_time overlaps with the other menu with the same dish. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: The only reliable method to avoid duplicates is to add constraint on db-level. Could you describe the requirements?

Comment: I updated the question. Please see the UPDATE section.

Comment: Problem is not that there is timegap between SELECT and INSERT. That is what I've used `select_for_update()` for. Ideally, it should block the next `SELECT` query, until the previous transaction is complete. And it's happening as per Django log (but the next SELECT query can't see the changes from previous INSERT statement. And AFAIK, postgres by default uses Read-Committed Isolation level for transaction. So, changes should be visible). BTW, the SELECT query blocking is not happening as per postgres log (You see, 2 SELECTs followed by 2 INSERTs). So, the behaviour is varying.

Comment: You are right - timegap act at different conditions. I've edited a recipe to validate data using standard db queries. Now you can be absolutely sure about duplicated reservations ;)

Comment: The `validate_unique` approach is similar to what I'm doing. Only the place of validation is changed from form to model. But with this I'll again face the same Race Condition issue? 2 concurrent create request will pass through successfully. As for second approach - db level validation (this could be looked upon). But I'll have to see if adding a new extension, just for one validation is overkill or there could be other easy way.

Comment: BTW, thanks for your answer. Learned new thing today. Didn't know about that extension :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107020/discussion-between-eugene-lisitsky-and-rohit-jain).